# Playing multiple videos on mobile devices (data saving?)

Tags: html, video, mobile

I have several videos that I'm trying to play on my website (about 5). Some of them play fine on mobile devices (I tested Safari and Chrome), but some don't play at all. These are videos that autoplay. I even tried delaying the play until the user scrolled into the viewport- no luck.

I think the browsers are trying to save data. Interestingly enough, if I close and reopen my browser, I'll see some of the videos playing. If I reopen, even the ones that were playing actually don't load the second time.

Is there any way to get around this?

url: https://stone.dolcedev.com

Comment: there's a limit to the number of connections a browser can have open to the same URL which may be causing a problem. do you have a sample link that shows the problem?

Comment: I added a URL in my question. Thank you

Comment: quick play here and if I scroll slowly then the videos do all load (after a couple of seconds). might be some network contention trying to load all of them at once. but one thing you could try is putting a couple on different domains (see http://www.browserscope.org/?category=network)

Comment: It works fine for me on desktop browsers, but on mobile I run into issues.